# a separable hilbert space and closed hyperplan

Tags: functional-analysis, separable-spaces

let $H$ be a separable hilbert space of infinite dimension and let $K$ a closed hyperplan .
I want to show that $H$ is homeomorphic to $K$ .

Answer (score 1):

$K$ is an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space, endowed with the restriction of the scalar product of $H$. The completeness follows from the fact that $K$ is closed.

There exists a bijective isometry between any infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space and $l^2$. Therefore there exists a bijective isometry between $H$ and $K$.